# Accessing sharepoint list with token unclear

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, azure-ad-msal

I only want to pull data from a list called *dataacq* within a group (or site?) called *prod* within the domain (or root site?) *tenant.sharepoint.com* (or *tenant-my.sharepoint.com* ?) and put it into a DataFrame.

I have an issue with the token gotten through `app.acquire_token_silent`.

Microsoft documentation is not comprehensible because it's too heavy and has little workable cookbooks/working examples (as can be seen by my numerous question marks). Also it seems they want to centralize all their APIs into `graph.microsoft.com`, yet there is no warning that `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/prod/_api/` is going to be discontinued.

I have gotten the following permissions from the azure portal for my app.
[image: Azure API permissions]

I don't believe I need all of them, but I am not sure. I just want to read a list. So is only `Microsoft Graph > Sites.read.All` necessary? Or is it `Sharepoint > Allsites.Read` ?
I know I both have an "app only" permission and a "signed in user" permission.

I did download the "quickstart" examples and I did read https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .  Although a token was successfully pulled using `app.acquire_token_silent`, using the returned token always throws some error whatever `scope` ('https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/.default' or 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default')  or API domain (`graph.microsoft.com` or `tenant.sharepoint.com`) I am using into a request:

```
{'error_description': 
     "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}
```

```
{'error': {'code': 'AccessDenied',
  'message': 'Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.',
  'innerError': {'date': '2021-02-19T08:05:16',
   'request-id': '01efc071-18e6-4006-8780-f771419ebe3e',
   'client-request-id': '01efc071-18e6-4006-8780-f771419ebe3e'}}}
```

On the other hand, there is an API developer testing portal. When I am copying the token given in this portal into my python code, both scope/API domains work.

This is e.g. an example that works with copying & pasting the token from the portal, but not working with the token issued by the `app.acquire_token_silent` method:

```py
r = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        fr'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/prod:/lists/{list_id}/items?expand=fields(select=Created))',
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token'],},)
```

So the issue is with this `app.acquire_token_silent` method or the configuration file. But the returned response seems alright:

```
{'token_type': 'Bearer',
 'expires_in': 3599,
 'ext_expires_in': 3599,
 'access_token': '...'}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code `r = requests.get.....` you provided in your description, it seems you use the microsoft graph api to implement it. If you use this api, you should use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as `scope` to get the access token. And you can copy the access token to this [page](https://jwt.io/), decode the token and check if the permissions are included in it.

And according to the screenshot of "**API permissions**" tab of your registered app, please also do grant admin consent operation for the permission `Sites.Read.All` although it shows not required admin consent.

================================**Update**===============================

It seems the method `acquire_token_silent()` acquire the access token by client credential flow. So we should add the "**Application**" type permission but not "**Delegated**" permission in registered app.

Comment: Yes, it was only an example with my request, I tried both scopes. And you can see the AllSites.Read is granted. What about the Sharepoint API scope?
I will try your page.

Comment: @Wli I don't know the scope for sharepoint api. Have you checked the access token(with microsoft graph scope) in jwt decode page ? Does it contain the permissions ?

Comment: ```'code': 'AccessDenied',
  'message': 'Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.'```

Comment: This is the response I get. The access token for both scopes could be decoded, but I am not sure where I should see the permissions.

Comment: @Wli Could you please copy the access token which get with `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` scope to the jwt decode page, and share the decoded response ?

Comment: Can I do that in public? ```Header:

{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "xxx",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "xxx",
  "kid": "xxx"
}

```

Comment: Payload
 ```{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxx",
  "iat": 10-figure number,
  "nbf": 10-figure number
  "exp": 10-figure number
  "aio": "XXXX",
  "app_displayname": "CoolName",
  "appid": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxx",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
  "rh": "0.xxx-xxx.",
  "sub": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
  "uti": "xxx",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 10-figure number
}```

Comment: I have tried to anonymize it as much as I could. Not sure how to decipher this.

Comment: @Wli It seems there are no permissions in your access token. How did you acquire the access token ? Could you please share the line of code `acquire_token_silent(...)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229144/discussion-between-wli-and-hury-shen).

Answer (score 0):

FFR, the key point to this solution is that you need to grant Graph permissions in Active Directory for your app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).